# How to measure the waveform of a piezo igniter?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-voltage, esd, piezo, spark

Is there a (cheap) way to measure the pulse of commercially available piezoelectric igniters like those used in lighters or BBQ grills?

[image: various piezo igniters]

I use them as a cheap (and very crude, for sure) method for ESD immunity testing. I am aware that this is not the best option as it has a few drawbacks compared to a calibrated ESD gun (probably higher voltage, higher energy level), but better than nothing. By now, I can only guess their voltage with the "1kV/mm" rule of thumb which is very inaccurate.

To get a better idea of what they output, I want to measure their waveform using an oscilloscope without destroying it.

Possible difficulties i see here are:

- Need for a high speed, high voltage probe (1000:1 perhaps, ignition voltage in the 15kV+ region)
- Need for a high bandwidth oscilloscope (for rise times in the ns region)

Comment: I would imagine stability of load capacitance between probed and no probe would be your major systematic error. Perhaps build 1000:1 capacitive voltage divider which also loads the piezo, making the input capacitor an air-spaced construction with adequate gaps and insulation, and keeping it connected, even in use.

Comment: and even **if** you could measure the voltage then re-creating a certain voltage would require a predictable force/speed application on the piezo igniter. I would investigate using a high voltage transformer (module) to charge a high voltage 100 pF capacitor (for ESD human body model).